# Why does FindInstance take so long: It is faster with more restrictions than with less?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, findinstance

> A support case with the identification [CASE:4347836] was created.

---

I just noted this little puzzle on [twitter](https://twitter.com/brilliantorg/status/1190614886394552320?s=20) by Brillant.org:

\begin{align} A B C\\+ BCA\\ = CDE \end{align}

Given that $A$ is even and $C$ is odd, what does this tell us about $B$? Is it (**1**) **odd** (**2**) **even**, or (**3**) could it be **even or odd**?

So why not give `FindInstance` a go at this? (We will not include strict inequality and checking for $A,C$ being even/odd at first)

```
FindInstance[
    100 a + 10 b + c + 100 b + 10 c + a == 100 c + 10 d + e
    && a != b != c != d
    && a ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && b ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && c ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && d ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && e ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    , { a, b, c, d, e }
    , Integers
    , 10
]

(*
{ {a -> 0, b -> 6, c -> 7, d -> 3, e -> 7}, {a -> 5, b -> 1, c -> 6, d -> 8, e -> 1},
  {a -> 6, b -> 1, c -> 7, d -> 9, e -> 3}, {a -> 6, b -> 1, c -> 8, d -> 0, e -> 4}, 
  {a -> 0, b -> 5, c -> 6, d -> 1, e -> 6}, {a -> 4, b -> 1, c -> 5, d -> 6, e -> 9}, 
  {a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 6, d -> 9, e -> 0}, {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 5, e -> 4}, 
  {a -> 0, b -> 7, c -> 8, d -> 5, e -> 8}, {a -> 2, b -> 4, c -> 7, d -> 1, e -> 9} }
 *)
```

The solutions are quickly found, but we want to make sure that $ a \neq b \ne c \ne d \ne e$ - which is fulfilled for some of the given solutions already.

But, if we expand the inequality restriction to include $E$ ...

```
FindInstance[
    100 a + 10 b + c + 100 b + 10 c + a == 100 c + 10 d + e
    && a != b != c != d != e
    && a ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && b ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && c ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && d ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && e ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    , { a, b, c, d, e }
    , Integers
]
```

... `FindInstance` runs "forever" on a fast laptop running Version 12.0 (Windows 64 bit). How can this be?

**Update**

What is even more puzzling: If we add **all puzzle restrictions**, `FindInstance` comes up with 6 candidates within 0.16 seconds on my machine (quickly showing that the correct answer is (3)):

```
FindInstance[
    100 a + 10 b + c + 100 b + 10 c + a == 100 c + 10 d + e
    && a != b != c != d != e
    && Mod[ a, 2 ] == 0
    && Mod[ c, 2 ] == 1 (* Thank you, @RolfMertig *)
    && a ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && b ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && c ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && d ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    && e ~ Between ~ { 0, 9 }
    , { a, b, c, d, e }
    , Integers
    , 10
]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.163391, Null} *)
```

But comment out `&& Mod[a,2]==0 && Mod[c,2] == 1` and `FindInstance` runs for minutes without any result (I gave up before an answer came up...). This looks "buggy" to me.

**Update 2**

The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divisible.html) tells us that:

> `Divisible[n, m]` is effectively equivalent to `Mod[n, m] == 0`

But replacing `Mod[a, 2] == 0` by `Divisible[a, 2]` in the code above will throw the error `FindInstance::naqs`:

> FindInstance:  ... is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming[tt = FindInstance[
    100*a + 10*b + c + 100*b + 10*c + 
       a == 100*c + 10*d + e && 
     a != b != c != d != e && 
     Mod[a, 2] == 0 && Mod[c, 2] == 1 && 
     Between[a, {0, 8}] && Between[b, 
      {0, 9}] && Between[c, {1, 9}] && 
     Between[d, {0, 9}] && Between[e, 
      {0, 9}], {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers, 
    10]]` executes in 0.15 seconds on my computer.

Comment: Your code after "Update" with `Mod[ c, 2 ] != 0` uses also 22 seconds on my machine. But if you replace `Mod[c,2]!=0` by `Mod[c,2]==1`, then it is fast ...

Comment: @Rolf Thanks for pointing out, I just noted the "little difference" and updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Version 12.1 this issue has been resolved.